# Auto layout error using UIDocumentMenuViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I'm getting an Autolayout error when use UIDocumentMenuViewController, the error came when the DocumentMenu is initialized, this is my code:

```
let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: doctypes, inMode: .Import) //Error message here
importMenu.delegate = self
importMenu.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = self.addButon;
self.presentViewController(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And this is the error, and is related to UICollectionViewFlowLayout

```
the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2016-02-17 13:28:44.538 App[35218:1131869] the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.
2016-02-17 13:28:44.538 App[35218:1131869] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fbcd5d18e90>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7fbcd6823000; frame = (0 44; 10 0); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fbcd3e63150>; animations = { bounds.origin=<CASpringAnimation: 0x7fbcd5c80c50>; bounds.size=<CASpringAnimation: 0x7fbcd5c80d40>; position=<CASpringAnimation: 0x7fbcd5c80e40>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbcd5d19450>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}> collection view layout: <_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fbcd5d18e90>.
2016-02-17 13:28:44.538 App[35218:1131869] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
```

I'm using Xcode v7.2 and my Deployment target is 8.0, this happens in iPhone and 
iPad, someone have faced with this error using UIDocumentMenuViewController?

This is the strange behavior:

[image]

**EDIT**: Also happens on Xcode 7.3

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: No yet, don't stop de execution but always in the console log

Comment: Oh, I can't get it to load anything past the iCloud action sheet.

Comment: Anybody have faced to this?

Comment: There is a reported Bug to apple with case number: 24858445, I hope to they fix it soon

Comment: Happens to be the duplicate and is already answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/41341552/4427884