# UIDocumentMenuViewController crashes on iPad but not on iPhone

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios9, uidocumentmenuvc

Presenting a `UIDocumentMenuViewController` to be able to load file into app. On iPhone it works, but not on iPad. Using iOS9. Any idea what is wrong?

```
dmvc = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: ["public.data"], inMode: .Import)
dmvc!.delegate = self
dmvc!.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = addSongButton
self.presentViewController(dmvc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

> 2016-06-07 09:45:45.256 Memorise[2994:977408] the behavior of the
>   UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because: 2016-06-07
>   09:45:45.260 Memorise[2994:977408] the item width must be less than
>   the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and
>   right values, minus the content insets left and right values.
>   2016-06-07 09:45:45.261 Memorise[2994:977408] The relevant
>   UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is
>   <_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x1668e6e0>, and it is
>   attached to ;
>   animations = { bounds.origin=;
>   bounds.size=;
>   position=; }; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}> collection
>   view layout: <_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x1668e6e0>.
>   2016-06-07 09:45:45.262 Memorise[2994:977408] Make a symbolic
>   breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch
>   this in the debugger.

What I do not understand why error message refers `collectionView`? I do not use collectionView at all. Maybe `UIDocumentMenuViewController` has it as inner component?

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25644145/3718570

Answer (score 7):

iPad has some special rules about ActionSheets and their cancel buttons, It usually depends on where you are displaying the ActionSheets from, so this is how you can resolve the crashing issue:

```
     let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypeHTML as String ], in: .import)
    importMenu.delegate = self
    importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    importMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I set the sourceView = self.view, and had to make a sourceRect = theButton.frame.